# write unit test for saving data into db

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

```
require_relative File.expand_path '../../test_helper',__FILE__

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    name "testinga again"
    finished  0
  end
end


class TaskTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  test "should not save tasks without title" do
    task = Task.new
    assert_equal false, task.save
  end

  test "should save tasks" do
    task = FactoryGirl.create(:task)
    assert_equal attributes_for(:task), task
  end  

end
```

I want to unit test the task creation process. In the `should save task` task, I have saved the value into the db, now I want to test if the saved value is equal to what i really sent to the db. How to do that or Am i even doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to check stuffs that are already been tested by industry leading engineers. If you see the `ActiveRecord` project, every API has been tested rigorously. So I recommend you skip this.

But, if your purpose is to learn UnitTesting, then again you are doing it wrong. Unittesting is a black-box testing. You are not supposed to call/invoke any other classes or third party softwares/services like `Database` in your case.

Lets call this a Integration Test.

---

> I want to test if the saved value is equal to what i really sent to
>   the db

Its easy; see:

```
  test "should save tasks" do
    task = FactoryGirl.build(:task, name: 'John')
    task.save
    assert_equal 'John', task.reload.name
  end
```

`reload` fetches the record from the database.

Comment: what if i want to test  `FactoryGirl.build(:task, name: 'John, finished: 0')` ?